# How to open csv file in Android?

Tags: android, filesystems

I've created a .csv file in SD card. Now I want to open this file but unable to do this.

How to open a .csv file?

Comment: May be, this post help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360628/get-and-parse-csv-file-in-android

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse the CSV file in android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057695/how-to-parse-the-csv-file-in-android-application)

Comment: Since its basically just another form of text file, this [general question for opening text files on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902689/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-from-the-sd-card-in-android) may help

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you design your XML in Android Studio, then you paste this line of code and check your apps. If you have any errors, you will send an error line or any feedback.

```
    csvText=findViewById(R.id.csvtext);
    select=findViewById(R.id.button);

    select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //imp step
            if(SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
            {
                if(Environment.isExternalStorageManager()){
                    //choosing csv file
                    Intent intent=new Intent();
                    intent.setType("*/*");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_AUTO_LAUNCH_SINGLE_CHOICE,true);
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select CSV File "),101);
                }
                else{
                    //getting permission from user
                    Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                    Uri uri=Uri.fromParts("package",getPackageName(),null);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
            else{
                // for below android 11

                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.setType("*/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_AUTO_LAUNCH_SINGLE_CHOICE,true);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[] {WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},102);


            }
        }
    });
}


Uri fileuri;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==101 && data!=null){
        fileuri=data.getData();
        csvText.setText(readCSVFile(getFilePathFromUri(fileuri)));
    }
}


// this method is used for getting file path from uri
public String getFilePathFromUri(Uri uri){
    String[] filename1;
    String fn;
    String filepath=uri.getPath();
    String filePath1[]=filepath.split(":");
    filename1 =filepath.split("/");
    fn=filename1[filename1.length-1];
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/"+filePath1[1];
}

//reading file data

public String readCSVFile(String path){
    String filedata = null;
    File file=new File(path);
    try {

        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){

            String line=scanner.nextLine();
            String [] splited=line.split(",");
            String row="";
            for (String s:splited){

                row=row+s+"  ";

            }

            filedata=filedata+row+"\n";

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return filedata;

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).