# hasMoreTokens function forcely close application

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to read a csv file with separator "!". But the moment I run following code in my android application, the whole application hangs. Please provide me help to solve the problem.

Input File looks like following, when opened in notepad:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


Line Number"!Shift!"QC Operator"!"Line Operator"!"Printing Operator"!"Product 
Group"!"Product Series"!Product!" Type of Defect"!"PCBType"!CORRECTIVE ACTION (CA)
1!DAY!Deepak!Chetan!Arun!TIMER!MM30XX!55Q!NO Solder!POWER!REWORK
2!NIGHT!Kajal!Kajal!Ashish!TEMP!MM10XX!55Q!Less solder!LOGIC!Replacement
3!!Kavita!Mahesh G!B.C!COUNTER!TC!EM306A!Dry solder!DISPLAY!NA
4!!Madhuri!Mahesh.P!Pabitra!PLC!PID !EM368 !IC PIN SOLDER SHORT!CARD!
5!!Namita!Namita!Sachin!METER!XT!EM368-C!Tombs toning!!
!!Sneha!Naveen!Sayali!DPM!800!MF16 !One side open !!

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Code for reading the file :

```
    public void ReadConfigFile() throws IOException 
{      
    File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "QCVerification"+ File.separator+"List of Entries.csv");
    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(fIn));
    String aDataRow = "";
    ArrayList<String> FileWholeData = new ArrayList<String>();
    FileWholeData.removeAll(null);
    while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        FileWholeData.add(aDataRow);
    }
    MyQcDataStructure = new QCDataStructure();
    for(Integer __index = 0;__index <FileWholeData.size();__index++)
    {   
        String TempString = "";
        TempString = FileWholeData.get(__index);
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(TempString,"!");   
        int columnIndex = 0;   
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) 
        {                  
            switch (columnIndex) 
            {     
            case 0:   
                MyQcDataStructure.QCLineNo.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
                break;
            case 1:
                    MyQcDataStructure.QCShift.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
                    break;
            case 2:
                    MyQcDataStructure.QCQCOPer.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
                    break;
            case 3:
                    MyQcDataStructure.QCLineOper.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
                    break;
            case 4:
                    MyQcDataStructure.QCPrintingOper.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
                    break;
            case 5:
                    MyQcDataStructure.QCProductGorup.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
                    break;
            case 6:
                    MyQcDataStructure.QCProductSeries.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
                    break;
            case 7:
                    MyQcDataStructure.QCProduct.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
                    break;
            case 8:
                    MyQcDataStructure.QCPDefect.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
                    break;
            case 9:
                    MyQcDataStructure.QCPCBType.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
                    break;
            case 10:
                    MyQcDataStructure.QCCA.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
                    break;
            }                      
            columnIndex++; 
        }
        break;
    }
    String aBuffer;
    aBuffer = "";
    for(int __secondIndex = 0;__secondIndex < MyQcDataStructure.QCLineNo.size();__secondIndex++)
    {
        aBuffer = aBuffer + MyQcDataStructure.QCLineNo.get(__secondIndex);
        aBuffer = aBuffer + "$";
        aBuffer = aBuffer + MyQcDataStructure.QCShift.get(__secondIndex);
        aBuffer = aBuffer + "$";
        aBuffer = aBuffer + MyQcDataStructure.QCQCOPer.get(__secondIndex);
        aBuffer = aBuffer + "$";
        aBuffer = aBuffer + MyQcDataStructure.QCLineOper.get(__secondIndex);
        aBuffer = aBuffer + "$";
        aBuffer = aBuffer + MyQcDataStructure.QCPrintingOper.get(__secondIndex);
        aBuffer = aBuffer + "$";
        aBuffer = aBuffer + MyQcDataStructure.QCProductGorup.get(__secondIndex);
        aBuffer = aBuffer + "$";
        aBuffer = aBuffer + MyQcDataStructure.QCProductSeries.get(__secondIndex);
        aBuffer = aBuffer + "$";
        aBuffer = aBuffer + MyQcDataStructure.QCProduct.get(__secondIndex);
        aBuffer = aBuffer + "$";
        aBuffer = aBuffer + MyQcDataStructure.QCPDefect.get(__secondIndex);
        aBuffer = aBuffer + "$";
        aBuffer = aBuffer + MyQcDataStructure.QCPCBType.get(__secondIndex);
        aBuffer = aBuffer + "$";
        aBuffer = aBuffer + MyQcDataStructure.QCCA.get(__secondIndex);
        aBuffer = aBuffer + "$";

    }
    txtData.setText(aBuffer);
    myReader.close();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            "Done reading santosh SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

But the application hangs when  following code runs in my application:

```
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) 
        {                  
            switch (columnIndex) 
            {
```

Any help to solve this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: `String aBuffer;` really wants to be a StringBuffer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057695/how-to-parse-the-csv-file-in-android-application

Comment: no problem is on this line..while loop hangs application..

Comment: Are there perhaps cases that are not covered in your switch? If this is the case, the tokenizer will not be advanced to the next element. Try adding a `default:` case and log if anything hits that.

Comment: no its not working with default condition also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a default case in your switch block. So when the column reaches 11, you have an infinite loop.

Add

```
default : 
    tokenizer.nextToken();
    break;
```

To your switch statement, or do

```
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens() && columnIndex <= 10)
```

Comment: Then add traces in your code or debug it to see where it hangs exactly. And ake sure that you don't have any exception thrown.