# Reading a csv file of LatLngs, adding to an ArrayList and then printing to google map fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, csv, arraylist

I'm looking to lay markers of around 60 LatLngs to a google map fragment. (They will be clustered, but that's another topic I think). I don't want to hardcode 60 variables, so I think storing them in a csv file and plotting them from there is probably better. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSV file might look like this:

```
48.45126,96.45631
46.56541,95.65476
47.56723,94.58639
```

You can store the file in the `res` folder, or you can store it on internal storage.  If you store your file in `res`, you will never be able to change it, as it is packaged with the APK and **read-only**.  See [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) for more details.  Either way, get your file:

```
InputStream instream = new FileInputStream("location_of_file.csv");
InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(inputreader);
List<LatLng> latLngList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
String line = "";

while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) // Read until end of file
{
  double lat = Double.parseDouble(line.split(",")[0]);
  double lon = Double.parseDouble(line.split(",")[1]);
  latLngList.add(new LatLng(lat, lon));
}

// Add them to map
for(LatLng pos : latLngList)
{
  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(pos)
        .title("Title!")); // Don't necessarily need title
}
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: This is an excellent help, thank you! Just to work out how to write a LatLng csv file now. Is it really as simple as your example?

Comment: Is what as simple as my example?  Reading the file?

Comment: the nature of the csv file

Comment: Yes it is - it simply means 'comma-seperated-value', and in your case you only need two values.  It is very easy to parse these files using Java's `split()` method

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**
Add your csv to your [Assets](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/store-and-use-files-in-assets/) folder

**Step 2**
Read in your csv file like

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("test.csv")));
```

**Step 3**
Parse your csv file

```
 String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         String[] RowData = line.split(",");
         date = RowData[0];
         value = RowData[1];
        // do something with "data" and "value"
    }
```

Check out

[Get and Parse CSV file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360628/get-and-parse-csv-file-in-android)

[How to parse the CSV file in android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057695/how-to-parse-the-csv-file-in-android-application)