# Reading Excel file in Android

Tags: android

I have one doubt regarding reading an Excel file in Android.

I have a button in XML file. When that button is clicked, it has to open the Excel file, which was there in my downloads, only for viewing purposes. Is it possible without using parsing techniques, converting Excel to sqlite?

Comment: Do you want to build your own excell editor or are you ok with using other editor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057695/how-to-parse-the-csv-file-in-android-application

Comment: i want to use my own excel file

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is any way to directly convert excel to sqlite as there isn't any direct relationship between them but to read any excel file in android you can use [this.](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt implementation from android.

Check this Blog post [export-and-import-data-db-table-to-csv](http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/09/export-and-import-data-db-table-to-csv.html).