# How to Read a csv or text file and put into list

Tags: android

I am new to android programming, I am trying to read a simple list , like a grocery list, from a text file (.txt) to put it into a list for an app I am making I was wondering how I would do this I or if anyone knows any tutorials for a simple tutorial.  I am also working this through with fragments.

Comment: I've seen answer for almoast the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902689/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-from-the-sd-card-in-android

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get and Parse CSV file in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360628/get-and-parse-csv-file-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link: [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

I used it to create a CSV file in code, but it also allows parsing a file.

But if you create the file manually anyway, why don't you use a string array and put it in your source-folder. Then add it to your listAdapter when you create the content for your list.