# How can i get the data for .csv File?

Tags: java, android, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to use .csv file in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385389/how-to-use-csv-file-in-android)

i created a sample Android application, in this i used .csv file to store the data. I placed this file in my **assetsfolder**.

In my .csv file contains,

```
1   Indonesia   Jakarta Phnom Penh  New Delhi
2   Bosnia  Pristina    Sarajevo    Prague
3   Germany Frankfurt   Bonn    Berlin
4   Kenya   Kinshasa    Nairobi Pretoria
5   Colombia    Lima    Buenos Aires    Bogota
```

how can i get the values for the .csv file using java code..

Comment: Are the separators tabs?

Comment: Aren't fields in .csv (Comma Separated Values) files, separated by a comma?

Comment: @Marcelo: yes, i used Comma (,)

Comment: Have you tried to use some of the libs suggested in [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385389/how-to-use-csv-file-in-android) from 4 hours ago?

Comment: @Marcelo the name CSV suggests the separators are commas but often people refer to files using other separators (tab stops, spaces, hashes, semi colons etc.) as CSV files :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to read in the file line by line and split each line by a separtor.

Basically like this:

```
try {
  File f = new File("yourpath");
  BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( f ) ) );
  String line = null;
  while ( (line = b.readLine() ) != null ) {
    String[] cells = line.split( "\t" );  //assuming the separator is a tab
    //do whatever you want, e.g. collect the arrays into a list etc.
  }
} catch( IOException e) {
  //do whatever is appropriate  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple to parse such a file using a StringTokenizer.

Lets assume you have the file opened and you are reading a single line at a time. To break up the string into tokens with each token representing a word you could do the following:

```
String lineOfText; // This contains the current line of text
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, ", "); // ' ' and ',' are use as delimiters to break up the line into individual tokens

ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>     
while(st.hasMoreElements())
     words.add(st.nextToken());
```

This will give you an array list with the individual words as elements of the list