# How to read csv file in android?

Tags: android, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get and Parse CSV file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360628/get-and-parse-csv-file-in-android)

I would like to store a csv file in android app itself & it should be called for read & later print the values according to the requirements.I definitely want the csv file to be called inside the app not outside the app[SD Card].Any examples on this will be really helpful.Thanks

Comment: Drop the CSV files into your Assets folder and use the OpenCSV library http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ to parse them.

Comment: I use Java CSV for my project. It is fast and light weight Link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have something like this;

```
public final List<String[]> readCsv(Context context) {
  List<String[]> questionList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
  AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

  try {
    InputStream csvStream = assetManager.open(CSV_PATH);
    InputStreamReader csvStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(csvStream);
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(csvStreamReader);
    String[] line;

    // throw away the header
    csvReader.readNext();

    while ((line = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
      questionList.add(line);
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return questionList;
}
```

Comment: Is the CSVReader an external jar...if so do you have an authenticated link for it..thanks for your reply..

Comment: The same as LuxuryMode suggested. http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my csv is of 1.5 mb size.When I give it I am not getting anything,but I am getting the output when on lower sizes.Do there is any constraint for csv size.

Comment: If you're getting nothing, I guess you're hitting the `catch` and doing the `e.printStackTrace()`. I suggest you look through your log to find this stack trace. Maybe you overflow some buffer, or maybe there's a bad character in there somewhere.

Comment: Yes I am getting this in the logcat Data exceeds UNCOMPRESS_DATA_MAX (1665199 vs 1048576),why cant I use any file larger than 1 mb.

Comment: I suggest look at the documentation on sourceforge. The limit will be there for a reason (especially in android, system memory is precious). There may be a better way to stream it in chunks. Or you may just be able to override the limit.

Comment: Is it possible to override the limit,if so please give me snippet on it.If I increase it what will be a permissible amount on it.