# Parse CSV files from a tornado web service within an Android app

Tags: java, android, web-services, csv, tornado

I have Tornado web service which returns a link after creating a CSV file as shown below.

```
http://10.0.2.2:8000/uploads/16165159GyjFImAYZssLEmn/16165159GyjFImAYZssLEmn.csv
```

Also I have outputted this URL within the Android application successfully. My question is how to parse the data of this file using the URL shown above. I have tried numerous ways and could not get it done. Can some one please help me to solve this problem. The code I have so far is as follows.

Also I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499351/how-to-read-csv-file-in-android) post as well, however still no success.

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(modifyURL);   
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    transformedImageURL = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);

    URL url = new URL(transformedImageURL);
    InputStream stream = url.openStream();
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
    ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(200);

    nt current = 0;

    while((current - bis.read()) != -1){
           baf.append((byte) current);
    }

    String stockText = new String(baf.toByteArray());
    String[] tokens = stockText.split(",");
    String testData = tokens[0];
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: And your exact problem is....

Comment: Application won't read data. I have separate threads, so it hangs