# Android - Import CSV File Into SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, csv

I want to enable my users to be able to import their CSV files into their SQLite Database, for now it will only be for one table which is called Inventory

How would I do it so that the user can select where the CSV file is within the app and then load in the data to the database WITHOUT replacing what is already there?

Comment: Can you please show to the community what have you done so far?

Comment: So far I've been looking online and only found examples where CSV files are in an Asset folder which I don't think is going to help me [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672074/import-csv-file-to-sqlite-in-android) Roughly third answer down, and so far haven't found much as to allowing users to select a file from a directory

Comment: Please have a look at the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must read content of csv file and add content to database.
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499351/how-to-read-csv-file-in-android) is for read from csv file.

edited

you can using this for read any csv file from storage

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("file/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
                Uri fileUri = data.getData();

                Log.i(getClass().getName(), "fileUri" + fileUri);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Hossein, thanks for the link, however how would I do it so that the user selects which CSV file to import

Comment: added file chooser for selecting any csv file