# Read CSV File in android app

Tags: android

Thanks in advance, 
How to read csv file from sdcard.
and how to give the permission of read/writer for file in android application.

thanks again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360628/get-and-parse-csv-file-in-android Possible duplicate?

Comment: no, that is very confusing, can you give any example link that will use further for us code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful to you

```
   File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
   File f = new File(dir, "path/dir1/sdcard.ext");
```

I don't know about the permissions but the above will certainly allow you to read the file from the sdcard in the path directory.