# AppInventor: Import data from csv file into a list

Tags: android, app-inventor

I am developing an android application..i want to import data from csv file into a list in appinventor..1 method is to upload that csv file online and then extract data from it..is there a way by which i can keep that csv file in sd card and get data from it? If I upload that csv file and then extract data from it, then what is the shortest and simplest way??Any examples??

Comment: [please also take a look how stackoverflow works](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask): in case the question is answered, mark the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer to mark it as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this is not possible with App Inventor, but there is a trick to read a text file from SD card: you can use App Inventor together with embedded HTML/JavaScript, see an example here: http://puravidaapps.com/read.php

Meanwhile I prepared another example which imports a multiline csv file stored as asset in App Inventor on first run of the app and stores it as list of lists in TinyDB. Please find it here: http://puravidaapps.com/importCSV.php

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can store a csv file in sdcard and write a small parser to parse csv file to construct your list. If the file is available somewhere remotely, I recommend to download the file first and then parse the file.

Answer from here -> [Get and Parse CSV file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360628/get-and-parse-csv-file-in-android)

```
  //--- Suppose you have input stream `is` of your csv file then:

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
try {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         String[] RowData = line.split(",");
         date = RowData[0];
         value = RowData[1];
        // do something with "data" and "value"
    }
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    // handle exception
}
finally {
    try {
        is.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

and may be have a look at this too,

http://code.google.com/p/secrets-for-android/source/browse/trunk/src/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader.java

Comment: this might be a good answer, but not for that question, which is about App Inventor http://www.appinventor.mit.edu/