# Can I add data from csv file in android?

Tags: android, csv

I am making an application of quotes. So can I bring data (quotes) from a csv file directly in Android? If yes please help!

Comment: Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167358/appinventor-import-data-from-csv-file-into-a-list

Comment: where is your effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can easily write data from csv file,as .csv file is Comma Seperated Value file so you can get data by splitting the file by ','

```
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(csv_file));
    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             String[] RowData = line.split(",");
             data = RowData[0];
             value = RowData[1];
            // do whatever you want to do with the data and value
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        // handle exception
    }

finally {
    try {
        csv_file.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```