# How to read and save contacts from csv file in android

Tags: java, android, csv

I have done with exporting phone contacts to csv file now i want  to read and save contacts from .csv file in android.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this as a regular phone user? Or you want to implement this in your app?

Comment: @Barney: i am trying to implement i am just new in android and dnt have a depth knowledge in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5360662/931982) answer

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             String[] RowData = line.split(",");
             date = RowData[0];
             value = RowData[1];
            // do something with "data" and "value"
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        // handle exception
    }
    finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
```