# android how can i get first row of CSV file in my application?

Tags: java, android, csv

i am developing quiz application in which i fet all question from CSV file.i fetch all the data from that file.but when set the data.it only set last row of csv file.can anyone help me?

here is my code:
public class EssentialQuiz extends Activity {

```
private ArrayList<String> questionList = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> option1list = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> option2list = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> option3list = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> option4list = new ArrayList<String>();

Button btnanswer1, btnanswer2, btnanswer3, btnanswer4;
Button btnback, btnnext;
TextView txtQuestion;
QuestionDemo currentQ;
List<QuestionDemo> quesList;
int score = 0;
private int pos = 0;
private int count = 0;
private int rand[] = new int[10];
boolean flag = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.question);
    initwidget();
    btnback.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.trans_right_in,
                    R.anim.trans_right_out);
        }
    });
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String next[] = {};
    try {
        InputStreamReader csvStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                EssentialQuiz.this.getAssets().open(
                        "essentialsfinalglossaryquiz.csv"));
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(csvStreamReader);
        for (;;) {
            next = reader.readNext();
            if (next != null) {
                list.add(next);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        questionList.add(list.get(i)[1]);
        option1list.add(list.get(i)[2]);
        option2list.add(list.get(i)[3]);
        option3list.add(list.get(i)[4]);
        option4list.add(list.get(i)[5]);

        System.out.println("Row::" + list.get(i)[1]);
        txtQuestion.setText(list.get(i)[1]);
        btnanswer1.setText(list.get(i)[2]);
        btnanswer2.setText(list.get(i)[3]);
        btnanswer3.setText(list.get(i)[4]);
        btnanswer4.setText(list.get(i)[5]);

        System.out.println("Row::" + list.get(i)[2]);
    }
```

Comment: Wish this will help you out: [Get and Parse CSV file in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360628/get-and-parse-csv-file-in-android)

Comment: What kind of separators does your csv file use? By default CSVReader uses , for fields. See - https://code.google.com/p/secrets-for-android/source/browse/trunk/src/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader.java

Comment: yes..i have used CSVReader.i want first question of CSV file and set it.how can i do this?