# Accessing/creating multi dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, multidimensional-array

I am fairly new to Java but am trying my best to learn. As a personal experiment I am writing a program that times the film developing process, fairly similar to the 'Massive Dev Chart' for Android and iPhone which I use quite a lot.

Following the code at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QeaXXpxNtq0, I have the following code to read a CSV file and generate a 2 dimensional array:

```
static String xStrPath;
static String[][] myArray;

static void setUpMyCSVArray() {
    myArray = new String[8702][8];

    Scanner scanLn = null;
    int Rowc = 0;
    int Row = 0;
    int Colc = 0;
    int Col = 0;
    String InputLine = "";
    double xnum = 0;
    String xfileLocation;

    xfileLocation = "database.csv";

    System.out.println("\n****** Setup Array ******");

    try {
        scanLn = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(xfileLocation)));

        while (scanLn.hasNextLine()) {
            InputLine = scanLn.nextLine();
            String[] InArray = InputLine.split(",");
            for (int x = 0; x < InArray.length; x++) {
                myArray [Rowc] [x] = InArray[x];

            }
            Rowc++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray[0]));
}
```

The CSV file looks like this:

```
Film Name        Developer    Dilution    ISO/ASA  35mm  120  Sheet  Temperature
Adox CHM 125,    510-Pyro,    1+100,      125,     7,    ,    ,      21C
Adox CHM 125,    510-Pyro,    1+500,      125,     50,   ,    ,      21C
Adox CHM 125,    777,         stock,      100,     12,   ,    ,      24C
Adox CHM 125,    A03,         stock,      125,     6.5,  ,    ,      20C
Adox CHM 125,    ACU-1,       1+10,       100,     9,    ,    ,      21C
Adox CHM 125,    Acufine,     stock,      125,     4,    ,    ,      20C
Adox CHM 125,    Acufine,     stock,      200,     6,    ,    ,      20C
Adox CHM 125,    Acufine,     stock,      320,     5,    ,    ,      21C
```

When I run:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray[0]));
```

The output is:

```
Adox CHM 125,    510-Pyro,    1+100,      125,     7,    ,    ,      21C
```

But I am unable to separate the data on that line, i.e. I want to run

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray[0][0]));
```

To output:

```
Adox CHM 125
```

After many attempts I am a little stuck as to what is going wrong with my code, any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you are not correctly reading the splited String. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360628/get-and-parse-csv-file-in-android

Comment: What does it print when you run `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray[0][0]));` ?
ANyway i think you can just ommit the `Arrays.toString` part. Just print `myArray[0][0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `Arrays.toString` if you want to print out a *whole* 1D array, because it convertes an array to a string. If you want to print out just one element of the array (like `myArray[0][0]` as you indicated), you would simply do this:

```
System.out.println(myArray[0][0]);
```

No need for the `Arrays.toString` there, because the elements of your jagged array are already `String`s.

Comment: Thank you, that did exactly what I wanted, looking at the answer it may be obvious that I am a Java rookie. I will accept the answer in a few minutes when stack overflow allows me to. Thank you

Comment: The answer may be obvious to me, but it wasn't to you, and there's no need to feel bad about it. I'm just glad I could help. :)

Comment: Thank you again, I suppose we all have to start somewhere :D

Answer (score 1):

`myArray` is an array, actually an array of arrays.  `myArray[0]` is therefore an array.  You can use `Arrays.toString()` on an array.

But `myArray[0][0]` is not an array, but rather an individual element.  Therefore `Arrays.toString()` can't be used on it.  It won't compile.

Since each element `myArray[i][j]` is a `String`, you don't need to do anything else to the element--just use it.

```
System.out.println(myArray[0][0]);
```