# How to attach data that will open with my android application

Tags: android, database

I am writing a speech enhancement app for android. I have a few matrices and vectors that were created from a training code that ran in MATLAB they are  saved as csv files .For the app to run the speech enhancement Alg. it needs to open these files and convert them to to arrays and 2d arrays.How can I attach these files to the andriod project to make this possible? (BTW I am working in Eclipse).

Comment: You are going to parse your csv files. [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5360628/655987). Creation of your arrays is up to you. If you want a more detailed explanation, try giving more information about you data and share your work.

Answer (score 0):

You can place them in the assets folder and then use AssetManager to get the files
InputStream inputStream = AssetManager.open(String fileName)