# How to read and edit csv file android?

Tags: android, csv

my aim is to read in a CSV file with ID's and fullnames. The app what I am designing is suppose to add to values to every row of the csv file and send it back to the web.

My question is how to get the csv from the web to the app and vice versa??

Comment: First you download it. Than you edit it. Finally upload.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get and Parse CSV file in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360628/get-and-parse-csv-file-in-android)